# Finding a Virtual Machine with OpenCV and Python wrapper

Tags: python, linux, macos, opencv, virtual-machine

I am trying to install OpenCV and its Python wrapper on my MacBook 10.11. I have been following a few tutorials but none of them have been successful.

I would like to know if it is possible to find a **Linux Virtual Machine with Python and OpenCV** already installed. I am sure it may help more than one person.

Thank you in advance !

FYI : One of the tutorial I used to install OpenCV is http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/ and at Step 4 I had this error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```